# Python Numpy Weighted Polynomial surface fit diverges at the edges

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have for example a 20 by 20 matrix. In the matrix I have background values around 1, and signal values around 3.5. I include an image just to represent the matrix data:
[image: matrix data plot]

I want to fit for each point (x and y) a surface by doing surface fitting. The way I did it is by creating a weight matrix, which for any value which is smaller than a cutoff value (1.1 for example), has a weight of 1, and any bigger value has a weight of zero. I have used the following code to create the weight matrix:

```
def Weight_Values_Excluded(data,cutoff_val=1.1):
    data_mat=np.copy(data)
    weight_mat=np.zeros(data_mat.shape)
    mask=(data_mat<=cutoff_val)
    weight_mat[mask]=1
    return weight_mat
```

Then I used the following code to do a weighted surface fit with a 6 order polynom:

```
def poly_fit(data_mat,weighted_mat,order=6):
    new_data=np.copy(data_mat)
    xarray=np.arange(new_data.shape[1])
    yarray=np.arange(new_data.shape[0])
    X,Y=np.meshgrid(xarray,yarray)
    surface=np.zeros(data_mat.shape)
    for i in range(new_data.shape[0]):
        polcoef=np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(xarray,new_data[i,:],order,w=weighted_mat[i,:])
        surface[i,:]=np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(xarray,polcoef)
    return X,Y,surface
```

The result is extremely weird. Even though My biggest value in the matrix is around 3.5, the surface I am creating diverges to around 900 at the edges. Included here an image of the fitted surface:

[image: Fitted Surface Example]

Does anyone can tell what is the problem with my code? Or anyone has a suggestion how to do a better weighted surface fit?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Isn't the behavior obvious?  You are fitting a series of 6 degree polynomials, one for each row in your data.  You weighted the values with signal as being zero.  Degree 6 polynomials with zero weights on the edges (where your signal predominantly is) are going to look like that.  Maybe reconsider how you are weighting --- shouldn't the signal be 1.0 and the background be 0.0?

Comment: I want to fit the background surface and not the signal. I want to correct the signal from the background as much as possible so I have created a theoretical surface to reduce at each point of the signal. I can however create edge weights which would be smaller than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `scipy.interpolate` ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#id1)). A sample using a smooth 2D spline (which is a piecewise polynom fit function):

```
from scipy.interpolate import SmoothBivariateSpline
#random points
pts = np.random.random((20,20)) * 3.5 + np.arange(400).reshape(20,20) * 0.01
#spline definition: note that I need to pass x, y and z to 1D. You can specify the degree of the polynom in x and y with kx and ky
sp = SmoothBivariateSpline(*map(np.ravel, np.meshgrid(np.arange(20), np.arange(20))), z=pts.T.ravel(), kx=3, ky=3)
```

A sample 2D slice (I'm not very good with 3D plots):

```
plt.plot(np.arange(20), sp(np.arange(20), 4), np.arange(20), pts[:,4], 'ro')
```

[image]

Comment: Yeap I have used the bisplrep function to fit a spline, But a spline fitting is a little too unrealistic to my taste though. It would fit everything. I wanted to have another polynomial fitting option.

Comment: Did you try adding more degrees (e.g. `kx=6, ky=6`)?

Comment: You can also force knots to make it more like a polynom and less like a piecewise polynom

Answer (score 1):

Interpolation with polynomials of large degree is prone to diverging oscillations, this is the so-called Runge phenomenon. Consider using splines (i.e. piecewise polynomials of low degree)